# How to get property of an form?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm querying a form on the console log. I want to return the "name" property of the fields on that form. I've gotten to the point where it will show the [constructor, constructor, constructor] on the console. Here's what i got:

```
var form = Ext.getCmp(formID);
var getFields = form.query('field');
console.log(getFields);

//^^ returns [constructor, constructor, constructor]
//   I need to get the names of those constructor ex: "field1, field2, field3"
```

Comment: just the developer console pressing F12

Comment: What does this `constructor` object look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var fieldNames = [];

for(var ii = 0; ii < getFields.length; ii++) {
    fieldNames.push(getFields[ii].getName());
}

console.log(fieldNames);
```

Comment: How would I take this object and pass it to a string?

Answer (score 2):

As per console logs, getFields is an array. You can retrieve values by iterating on it

```
for(var i = 0; i < getFields.length; i++) {
    console.log(getFields[i]);
}
```

Comment: yes, but i want to get the property from that array such as "name", ^^ returns constructor {initialConfig: Object, id: "Field", autoGenId: true, protoEl: null, config: Object…}

Comment: Let us say each field element is an object. Then you can get the value by getFields[i].name

Comment: is there anyway to output the fields to be on one line.

Comment: var fields = []; for(){ fields.push(getFields[i].getName());} console.log(fields);

Comment: @Grammin Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: You were getting the uncaught syntaxerror because the for loop has to have logic in it.  I just didn't put it in there for the example.

Answer (score -1):

if JQuery is present try this.

```
for(var i = 0; i < getFields.length; i++) {
   console.log($(getFields[i]).attr('name'));
}
```

or without JQuery

```
for(var i = 0; i < getFields.length; i++) {
   console.log(getFields[i].getAttribute("name"));
}
```

Comment: console.log(getFields[i].getName());

Comment: this code doesnt work, @TheNewGuyOnTheRock ?`console.log(getFields[i].getAttribute("name"))`